# django limiting file size and file format in view

Tags: python, django, filesize, file-format

In my view I am getting a file like :

```
def add_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_files = request.FILES.getlist("file")
        for file in my_files:
            Here if file is greater than 2 Mb raise error and send error message
            Also check if the file is of type jpg. If it is then return something
```

How can I do this ? I want to do it by taking constant variable from settings. Like setting MEDIA_TYPE or MIME_FORMAT in settings and also file size in setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
CONTENT_TYPES = ['image']
MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE = "2621440"
content = request.FILES.getlist("file")
content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
if content_type in CONTENT_TYPES:
    if content._size > MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE:
        #raise size error
    if not content.name.endswith('.jpg'):
       #raise jot jpg error
else:
    #raise content type error
```

**UPDATED**

If you want a `form` validation, try this:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_file(self):
        CONTENT_TYPES = ['image']
        MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE = "2621440"
        content = self.cleaned_data['file']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in CONTENT_TYPES:
            if content._size > MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE:
                msg = 'Keep your file size under %s. actual size %s'\
                        % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE), filesizeformat(content._size))
                raise forms.ValidationError(msg)

            if not content.name.endswith('.jpg'):
                msg = 'Your file is not jpg'
                raise forms.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('File not supported')
        return content
```

Comment: I only want it to submit the photo of type jpg.. how to do that ?

Comment: also here content = request.FILES.getlist("file") is list of image. I want to check this for every image

Comment: @aryan just iterate over them and validate each one, using the form provided above or just validation code directly.

Comment: Small correction in your code `MAX_UPLOAD_PHOTO_SIZE = "2621440"` this should be an integer.